# MYSQL Trigger insert or update different table

Tags: mysql, triggers, where-clause, insert-update

I've been wrapping my head around this SQL statement I'm trying to make and I've reached a wall so to speak, if you could lend any advise as to what I am doing wrong that would be a big help. I get the error around the 2nd where statement but I dont really expect the last part of the code to work yet.

> ```
> CREATE TRIGGER UpdateScores
> AFTER INSERT ON CharSheet FOR EACH ROW
> begin
>        DECLARE id_exists Boolean;
>               SELECT
>               1
>        INTO
>               @id_exists
>        FROM
>               ScoresTable
>        WHERE
>               ScoresTable.PlayerID= NEW.PlayerID;
>
>        IF @id_exists = 1
>        THEN
>            UPDATE
>                   ScoresTable
>            SET 
>                   Exp = :New.Exp;
>            WHERE 
>                   ScoresTable.PlayerID = :NEW.PlayerID;
>         END IF;
>
>         IF @id_exists = 0
>         THEN
>          -- I don't expect this part to work yet.
>           INSERT INTO ScoresTable VALUES (:New.PlayerID, :New.Race, :New.Class, :New.Exp);
>         END IF;
> END;
> $$
> ```

Comment: And what is the error?

Comment: Pretty vague

#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near ':New.Exp; WHERE ScoresTable.PlayerID = :NEW.Play' at line 19

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is in this block of code:

```
   THEN
       UPDATE
              ScoresTable
       SET 
              Exp = :New.Exp;
       WHERE 
              ScoresTable.PlayerID = :NEW.PlayerID;
    END IF;
```

Remove the semicolon at the end of the `set` statement.

Comment: Thanks for the quick help.

getting this now but atleast its moving along now :D
#1142 - TRIGGER command denied to user 'TrolAccounts'@'**.***.**.***' for table 'CharSheet'